# Insert getting different values using IN, while doing an INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, inner-join, workbench

The problem is at the time the selected data is inserted in a new table.

Here is my query;

```
INSERT INTO `pdctarifahmgpo_x_mepo` (`idservicio_hm_x_mepo`, `cuenta_hm_x_mepo`, `dependencia_hm_x_mepo`,
        `fecha_hm_x_mepo`, `mes_hm_x_mepo`, `consumo_hm_x_mepo`, `costo_hm_x_mepo`)
(SELECT
a.servicio,
b.cuenta,
b.dependencia,
a.periodo_fin,
MONTHNAME(a.periodo_fin),
CONCAT('', (a.consumo)),
CONCAT('', (a.costo))
FROM `pdc_consumo_energia` a
INNER JOIN `pdc_servicios_energia` b ON a.servicio = b.id
WHERE a.servicio IS NOT NULL AND a.servicio <> ''
AND b.cuenta IS NOT NULL AND b.cuenta <> ''
AND b.dependencia IS NOT NULL AND b.dependencia <> ''
AND a.periodo_fin IS NOT NULL AND a.periodo_fin <> ''
AND a.consumo IS NOT NULL AND a.consumo <> ''
AND a.costo IS NOT NULL AND a.costo <> ''
AND a.servicio <> '192'
AND (YEAR(a.periodo_fin) >= 2011 AND YEAR(a.periodo_fin) <=YEAR(NOW()))
AND b.cuenta IN(..., 999941000123)
ORDER BY a.periodo_fin ASC, MONTHNAME(a.periodo_fin) ASC);
```

I have executed the SELECT by itself and it shows the correct data, but while doing the INSERT, it gets values modified with zeros like this '999941000000'
in the **"cuenta_hm_x_mepo"** COLUMN or **deletes** the **"-"** and next numbers, in the selected values like this; **AND b.cuenta IN(...,'4001370-01', , '5333427-01')**.

Here is the query that creates the table;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pdctarifahmgpo_x_mepo` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `idservicio_hm_x_mepo` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, `cuenta_hm_x_mepo` FLOAT NOT NULL,
            `dependencia_hm_x_mepo` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL , `fecha_hm_x_mepo` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            `mes_hm_x_mepo` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, `consumo_hm_x_mepo` DECIMAL(30,2) NOT NULL,
            `costo_hm_x_mepo` DECIMAL(30,2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
            UNIQUE KEY (`id`))  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Maybe is the **IN** function causing this issue?
The field structure is similar to the original table. Tried one single value and the result is the same. Any ideas why is getting this?

Results using select
[image]
Results using insert
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cuenta_hm_x_mepo FLOAT NOT NULL` column needs to be `cuenta_hm_x_mepo BIGINT NOT NULL` in order to store the long integer number properly. The `FLOAT` data type does not provide sufficient accuracy to store a 12 digit integer number.

If you really want to store the value in a floating point format you could also use `DOUBLE` as the data type. Checkout [this page for MySQL data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html).

Comment: Oh thanks cars10m, I did not knew that, still a rookie using queries like those.